# Python backoff decorator library for retrying with exception treatment

Tags: python

I need the function do_it retrying up to 10 times if any exception is raised, with an interval of 0.5 to 1.5 seconds between retries.

I am trying to do it with [backoff decorator](https://pypi.org/project/backoff/) and the following code:

```
import backoff

x = 0

@backoff.on_exception(max_tries=10)
def do_it():
    global x
    x = x + 1
    print(f'x: {x}')
    try:
        z = downloaded_from_somewhere('http://somewhere.com/z')  # download may fail
        y = 1/z   # z may be equal to zero, that will raise a division per zero and fail
        return y
    except:
        return f'Error after {x} tries'

do_it()
```

The function may raise an exception due to different failures in `try:`
After 10 retries it will return `Error after {x} tries`

The backoff decorator library documentation is precarious.

How to correctly specify the decorator parameters `@backoff.on_exception(max_tries=10, something_else=blablabla, and_other=blabla2)` to have the function working properly?

Comment: Your function doesn't raise an exception: it *captures* all exceptions with a blank `except:`, and only ever exits with a regular `return` statement. You should never use a blank `except:` like that because it will hide a variety of coding errors and make simple problems much harder to diagnose.

Comment: Indeed, hardly every use a blank 'except:' anyway as it traps everything including program exit!  Always at least use 'except Exception:' but, as noted, the existence of the try: will stop your function raising an exception unless you put a 'raise' in the exception handling part.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @larsks and @Thickycat, but if the function fail after the 10 retries, how to instruct my code on how to move forward without the (`try:` and) `except:` ?  (I am not very experienced in Python as you can see)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> but if the function fail after the 10 retries, how to instruct my code on how to move forward

First, a caveat: the usage of the `backoff` decorator you show in your question is invalid; you *must* provide the `wait_gen` and `exception` parameters.

If you're using the `backoff.on_exception` method, then you *want* your function to raise an exception on failure. This is how the `backoff` decorator knows to retry your function. For example, consider the following, in which we have a function that fails 80% of the time:

```
import backoff
import random


@backoff.on_exception(backoff.constant, ValueError, interval=1, max_tries=5)
def do_it():
    x = random.randint(0, 100)
    if x < 80:
        print("Failed!")
        raise ValueError("Failed!")

    print("Success!")


do_it()
```

This will retry `do_it()` up to five times; if it fails more than five times, the exception bubbles up to the calling code. Running the above looks like this if it succeeds within `max_tries`:

```
Failed!
Failed!
Success!
```

And like this if it fails five times:

```
Failed!
Failed!
Failed!
Failed!
Failed!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lars/tmp/python/backofftest.py", line 15, in <module>
    do_it()
  File "/home/lars/.local/share/virtualenvs/python-LD_ZK5QN/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/backoff/_sync.py", line 105, in retry
    ret = target(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/lars/tmp/python/backofftest.py", line 10, in do_it
    raise ValueError("Failed!")
ValueError: Failed!
```

Presumably if the function fails more than `max_tries` times, you would catch that exception in the calling code and exit gracefully with an appropriate error message:

```
try:
  do_it()
except ValueError as err:
  sys.exit("failed to do the thing")
```

(Note that in this example I'm using a constant backoff period via `backoff.constant`; in practice, you would probably use `backoff.expo` instead for exponential backoff behavior.)

Comment: Thank you for the valuable information.
I could adapt your code to make it do what I need!

Comment: This is explained so well!

Comment: One of the most useful, well-written and polite answers I've seen on SO. Thanks!